# Is it possible to insert content into a DIV but have the DIV remain the same size?

Tags: html, css

I have three DIV elements filling out the viewport. All three DIVs have `position: absolute`, `left: 0px` and `width: 100%`.

The top DIV has `height: 10%`, the middle DIV has `height: 88%` and the bottom DIV has `height: 2%`.

For example, is there a way for me to insert text into the top DIV and have it remain at a height of 10%? Because 10% is big enough to contain the text without the DIV growing... but the DIV grows anyway.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/style.css' />
</head>
<body>

    <div id="bodyWrap">
        <div id="header" class="box">
        a
        </div>
        <div id="mid"  class="box">
        a
        </div>
        <div id="footer"  class="box">
        a
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@font-face{ 
    font-family: gab; 
    src: url('gabriola.ttf');
}

#bodyWrap
{
    /*If ever necessary.*/
    text-align: center;
    font-family: gab;
}

.box
{
    background-color: rgb(216, 179, 126);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0px;
}

#header
{
    height: 10%;
    top: 0px;
}

#mid
{
    height: 88%;
    top: 10%;
}

#footer
{
    height: 2%;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: yes give it some height and overflow:auto

Comment: the divs will stay the height you set them to, you just need to set what to do with the overflow.   Try `overflow:auto`  I think you are missing the following as well: `html, body, #bodyWrap {height:100%;}` otherwise the divs won't know what height to be a percentage of

Answer (score 0):

Just add `overflow: auto;` to the `div`

```css
.editable {
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='editable' contenteditable="true">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
  software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#header
{
    height: 10%;
    top: 0px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```